# android/java - Parsing JSON responses of different structure

Tags: java, android, json

I have REST web service that has different responses containing some user information like this

```
{"id": 1,"fullname": "NV","login": "bravenewuser","sex": "M","mail":"aaa@gmail.com","photo": "","status": "","birthDate": "1900-01-11T00:00:00Z","registrationDate": "1900-05-13T00:00:00Z","phoneNumber": "9010"}
```

and like this

```
[{"id":2,"userId":0,"timeStart":"2017-08-21T13:05:00Z","active":true,"title":"Woman","artist":"Wolfmother","length":"00:04:00"},{"id":1,"userId":0,"timeStart":"2017-08-20T13:05:34Z","active":true,"title":"Dont call","artist":"Royal blood","length":"00:03:20"}]
```

with list of user's listenings

Say I have two classes `User` and `Listening` (may be in addition I need `ListOfListenings` wrapper-class). May be in future i would like to retrieve some more information from service and get responses having some another structure.

The question is what is the best way to parse different responses in one place (method or class) of the code?

I use `com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient` for calling service. So can I try something like this:

1. Write one common response handler for different types of response:

   ```
   public class CommonResponseHandler <T extends Entity> extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {
       private T response;

       public T getResponse() {
           return this.response; //return pasing result
       }

       @Override
       public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
           /*parsing response body into this.response*/
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
           ///...
       }
   }
   ```
2. and then call service like this

   ```
   public User getUser(String url, RequestParams someparams) {
       AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
       CommonResponseHandler<User> handler = new CommonResponseHandler<>();
       client.get(url, someparams, handler );
       return handler.getResponse();
   }
   ```

Can I simplify parsing different types of responses by this way. And if not, what is better (or even the best) way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two response handlers.

```
public class ObjectResponseHandler <T extends Entity> extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {
    private T response;

    public T getResponse() {
        return this.response; //return pasing result
    }
}
```

And,

```
public class ArrayResponseHandler <T extends Entity> extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {
    private List<T> responses;

    public List<T> getResponses() {
        return this.responses; //return pasing result
    }
}
```

And, if your JSON is only going to be a JsonArray or JsonObject. You can check for it using

```
 anyJsonString.startsWith("[") => true => use ArrayResponseHandler
 anyJsonString.startsWith("{") => true => use ObjectResponseHandler
```

If you want to keep using getResponse() as an object, you should create something like

```
public class ListWrapper<T> {

    List<T> list;

    public ListWrapper (List<T> list) { this.list = list; }

    public List<T> getList () { return list; }        

}
```

And, use it in ArrayResponseHandler, like

```
 public ListWrapper getResponse() {
     return new ListWrapper<T>(responses);
 }
```

Comment: Looks like perfect answer .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. @rupinderjeet